# Add a custom text when a product sold individually message in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

In Woocommerce I would like to add a text message in single product pages if the product is sold individually,  just after short description:

[image: In this image you can see the rectangle where I need the message]

In this screenshot I would like to replace the red rectangle by "You can only buy one piece of this product".

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(Updated)** This hooked function will add a custom text when product is sold individually in single product pages after the short description:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'sold_individually_custom_text', 25 );
function sold_individually_custom_text(){
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_sold_individually( ) ) {
        echo '<p class="sold-individually">' . __("You can only buy one piece of this product", "woocommerce") . '</p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).